# How to combine a sequence of citations in the same parenthesis?

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

I'm trying to put in the same parenthesis a sequence of citations.

I use this:

```
\cite{cit1},\cite{cit2}
```

and the result is the following:

```
[50],[51]
```

Instead of this, I'd like to obtain the following:

```
[50, 51]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: \cite{key1,key2}?

Comment: Please tell us (a) which bibliography style you employ and (b) whether or not you employ a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: If I use {key1,key2} values are separated by";" not comma.
The citation style is ieeetr without natbib.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: if you are using `natbib` styles, use the option `sort&compress`, like \usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package and the `ieeetr` bibliography style, you should be able to achieve your formatting objective by (a) running

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}
```

in the preamble and (b) grouping two or more cite keys in the argument of `\cite`:

```
\cite{key1,key2[,...]}
```

---

A separate comment: The `ieeetr` bibliography style has been more or less unchanged since the mid-1980s. As such, it no longer represents current IEEEtran  formatting guidelines. You may want to think about replacing `\bibliographstyle{ieeetr}` with `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`.